# Can Visual Studio remove explicit namespace from declarations?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

I just converted 10 years of code from VB to c# and I'm currently trying to clean the converted code.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to replace existing class name for a shortest definition that would consider the using statements previously defined?

ex: I would like this line

```
System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter myDbDataAdapter;
```

to be converted to

```
DbDataAdapter myDbDataAdapter;
```

if the `using System.Data.Common;` is in the file.

Comment: I don't know about "naked" VS, but Resharper can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that was my thought too. Give the trial of ReSharper a go. The format file functions has options to do this. You can even to it for whole solutions.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: Depending on what you are doing they do have [several ways](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/index.jsp) to get the program free. Open Source projects, Classrooms, Students (the license says you can only use it on homework though), and active Microsoft MVP members all get it free.